# Already existing GUI for OpenCV

Tags: opencv, user-interface

Is there any GUI on the internet which support some kind of visual programming for openCV?

I've been given the task to find something, like this, but haven't been able to find any.. Something using blocks and connecting them together and so on??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check QT based  [Designer tool](http://qvision.sourceforge.net/TheDesignerGUI.html) from the [QVision Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qvision/) even if one and half of the year passed since the last project update.

Answer (score 0):

[zGUI][1]https://github.com/zetapark/zGUI

I just uploaded a opencv gui toolkit. Please take a look.. This is solely dependent on opencv. Event driven..